# how do I redraw an image using python's matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

What I am trying to do seems to be fairly straightforward, but I'm having a heck of a time trying to get it to work. I am simply trying to draw an image using imshow and then re-draw it periodically as new data arrives.

I've started out with this:

```
fig = figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0,200),ylim=(0,200))
myimg = ax.imshow(zeros((200,200),float))
```

Then I'm assuming I can call set_data like this to update the image:

```
myimg.set_data(newdata)
```

I've tried many other things, for example I've called `ax.imshow(newdata)` instead or I've tried using `figure.show()` after `set_data()`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can simply call figure.canvas.draw() each time you append something new to the figure. This will refresh the plot.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from builtins import input

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca()
fig.show()

block = False
for i in range(10):
    ax.plot(i, i, 'ko')
    fig.canvas.draw()
    if block: 
        input('pause : press any key ...')
    else:
        plt.pause(0.1)
plt.close(fig)
```

Comment: This got me a step closer. When I run your code above, it opens a figure at the start of execution and draws the final plot only at the end of execution (rather than having a dot appear each time I hit return). I'm running python 2.7 in spider on windows 7, if that's of any consequence.

Comment: I don't know. I have tested it on both linux and windows7 and it works. This could maybe come from your version of matplotlib. I believe that the syntax may change between different versions. I am using matplotlib 1.2.0

Comment: I found out that if you do a plt.pause() in there, it gives the figure a chance to redraw before continuing execution. Other methods of inserting a wait don't do this.