# Redraw a matplotlib figure with new rc params

Tags: python, matplotlib

is there a conventient way to update an already existing matplotlib figure with new rcParams? Background is that i want to export figures with different properties (e.g. line-width, fonts ..). Is there something like a 'redraw()' option? 
Thank you!

Comment: Could you not set the rcParams before each plot?

Comment: No, because the onscreen figures should not necessarily look like the exported ones.

Answer (score 1):

use `fig.canvas.draw()`

See [How to update a plot in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098131/how-to-update-a-plot-in-matplotlib)
 or [how do I redraw an image using python's matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20936817/how-do-i-redraw-an-image-using-pythons-matplotlib)

In a jupyter notebook:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

mpl.rcParams['figure.figsize']=(5,5)
mpl.rcParams['font.size']=50

fig = plt.figure()
x = [1,2,3]
y = [3,4,5]

plt.plot(x,y,label='data')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

mpl.rcParams['font.size']=5
fig.canvas.draw()
fig.savefig('saved.png')

from IPython.display import Image
Image('saved.png')
```

[image]

Comment: I have trouble recreating your code. The second plot has always the same fontsize as the first one. I'm using Python 3.9.10, matplotlib 3.5.3, jupyterlab 3.4.5.